# swapping elements in 8x8 matrix in javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I am trying to impliment a checkers game and have a 8x8 matrix. At the moment I am just trying to replace one element with another so that I can simulate a makeMove() action. so if a 'wht' piece wants to go diagonally, it should take the place of an "X" as its new position and the position the peice was moved from should have an "X" there signifying that it's place is empty.

I've tried creating a board.splice() method but it gives me a typerError. I am trying to play around with a nested for loop now but also to no avail. Any help would be great.

```
board = [
    [' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht'],
    ['wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X '],
    [' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht'],
    [' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X '],
    [' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X '],
    ['red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X '],
    [' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red'],
    ['red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ']
  ];

makeMove = function(row1, col1, row2, col2) {
   // board.splice(board[row1][col1],1,board[row2][col2]);
   // board.splice(board[row2][col2],1,board[row1][col1]);

   for(var i = 0; i < bounce.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < i.length; j++){

   }

   displayBoard();
}
```

Comment: var col=board[row1][col1]; board[row1][col1]=" X "; board[row2][col2]=col;

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to add an X object with its coords:
var x = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}
Next you should add switch statement which makes moves and checks if you don't go out of matrix. How to split values is shown in comment above.